# An unhandled exception of type 'RDotNet.EvaluationException' occurred in RDotNet.dll

Tags: c#, r, windows, nfs, r.net

R.Net is throwing error while using Network File path in a Windows Forms application.

```
engine.Evaluate("source('\\\\Something.x.y.z.edu/SomeLocation/SomeFile.R');");
```

While the same statement works if I try to run the line `source('\\\\Something.x.y.z.edu/SomeLocation/SomeFile.R');` in R or RStudio.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need in C#

```
engine.Evaluate("source('\\\\\\\\Something.x.y.z.edu/SomeLocation/SomeFile.R');");
```

so that the string

```
"source('\\\\Something.x.y.z.edu/SomeLocation/SomeFile.R');"
```

is passed to R.